# Java mail ,unable to read “.msg attachment” sent from outlook client

Tags: java, email, outlook, jakarta-mail

I met nearly same problem which mentioned in following URL
 [Java mail Api ,unable to read ".msg attachment" from outlook client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928835/java-mail-api-unable-to-read-msg-attachment-from-outlook-client)

If anyone has a solution to read ".msg attachment" sent from outlook client by javamail (no issue if email sent from web mail console), pls. let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is the MIME type of the .msg attachment?  If it's a Microsoft proprietary type, the [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/hsmf/index.html) project may help.